# How does the stackoverflow suggestion works?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, theory, bigdata

What is the theory behind the algorithms, that for example, generate the suggestions on stackoverflow site for similar questions while you write one? Could you recommend some books on the subject?

Comment: Voting to migrate this to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: It is more about the algorithms in general than about the site itself. Stackoverflow is just given as a very immediate example :)

Comment: Either meta.SO or programmers.SE is a better fit, as outlined in the various site FAQs.

Comment: I know, but I think you're more likely to get an answer there since that's where all the devs hang out.

Comment: It is closely related to the subject of query prediction. I found this article: [context sensitive query auto completion](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~nkraus/papers/fr332-bar-yossef.pdf) facinating

Comment: Since this didn't migrate, I'm voting to re-open it since it's a legit question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithms you talk about are found mainly in 3 [AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) branches: [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), [ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) and [IR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval).

For example to find the most similar 10 questions of a new question one could extract [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) from the texts of each question, compute [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) weight vectors for each question's n-grams, then compute the [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between the new question and all the other questions, and choose the 10 questions with the highest similarities.

Some free books you can read:
http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/
http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html

And a 2 free courses starting late January:
http://www.nlp-class.org/
http://jan2012.ml-class.org/

Also (kind of involved):
http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=63480b48-8819-4efd-8412-263f1a472f5a
http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=348ca38a-3a6d-4052-937d-cb017338d7b1

Comment: You gave me some food for thought :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with **Association Rule Mining** that originated from market basket analysis. For a good reference, *Web Data Mining* by Bing Liu is definitely one of the best.